# Покадровая смена изображений

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Как сделать подобную анимацию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пишу следующее

***HTML***

```
<div class="pos">
  <div class="q-1 active"></div>
  <div class="q-2 active"></div>
  <div class="q-3 active"></div>
  <div class="q-4 active"></div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.pos {
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.q-1,
.q-2,
.q-3,
.q-4,
.q-5,
.q-6,
.q-7 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
}
.q-1.active:after{
  position: absolute;
  content:url('flower-1.png');
  height:145px;
  top:-145;
}
.q-2.active:after{
  position: absolute;
  content:url('flower-2.png');
  height: 91px;
  top: -92px;
}
.q-3.active:after{
  position: absolute;
  content:url('flower-3.png');
  height: 120px;
  top: -120px;
}
.q-4.active:after{
  position: absolute;
  content:url('flower-4.png');
  height: 95px;
  top: -95px;
}
```

***JS***

```
el=$(".pos div")
cnt=0
$(".pos div").each(function(i,e){
  setInterval(function(){
    el.eq(cnt++).addClass("active")
  },2000)  
  el.removeClass("active")
})
```

Comment: пишу следующее........и......?

Comment: что и?,неполучилось

Comment: А что именно не получилось - надо бы догадаться, да? Были ли ошибки или просто код встает с кресла и бьет учебником по голове? А где html разметка? А где точки с запятыми в коде? Бастуют?

Comment: Есть вот такая простая либа для спрайтовых анимаций: http://blaiprat.github.io/jquery.animateSprite

Comment: html добавил,нет эта либа не подходит

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский неполучается нормально двить следующему элементу класс актив и убрать его у текущего элемента

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var func = window.setInterval(start, 2000),
    els = $("div"),
    cnt = 0;

function start() {
  cnt = (cnt === els.length) ? 0 : cnt;
  
  els.removeClass("active");
  els.eq(cnt++).addClass("active")
}
```

```css
.q-1,
.q-2,
.q-3,
.q-4,
.q-5,
.q-6,
.q-7 {
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 145px;
  width: 40px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px red;
  font: bold 1em sans-serif;
}

.q-1.active:after,
.q-2.active:after,
.q-3.active:after,
.q-4.active:after,
.q-5.active:after,
.q-6.active:after,
.q-7.active:after {
  position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    top: 10px;
}

.q-1.active:after{ content:"1"; }
.q-2.active:after{ content:"2"; }
.q-3.active:after{ content:"3"; }
.q-4.active:after{ content:"4"; }
.q-5.active:after{ content:"5"; }
.q-6.active:after{ content:"6"; }
.q-7.active:after{ content:"7"; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="q-1"></div>
<div class="q-2"></div>
<div class="q-3"></div>
<div class="q-4"></div>
<div class="q-5"></div>
<div class="q-6"></div>
<div class="q-7"></div>
```

Comment: Вы забыли условие добавить обнуление счетчика

Comment: @АлексейШиманский поправил :)